# Autosuggestion not working for importing MUI components from node modules in React JavaScript project using Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, material-ui, vite

I'm encountering an issue with autosuggestion in Visual Studio Code (VSCode) when trying to import MUI (Material-UI) components from node modules in my React JavaScript project built with Vite. The autosuggestion feature doesn't seem to work as expected, making it difficult to import the necessary components.

Here are the details of my setup:

IDE: Visual Studio Code (VSCode)
Project: React JavaScript project
Build tool: Vite
UI library: Material-UI (MUI)

The issue arises when I try to import MUI components from the node modules. I expect VSCode to suggest the available components as I type, but the autosuggestion feature doesn't seem to pick up the MUI components.

I have already tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Restarted VSCode: I restarted my IDE to ensure that any temporary glitches were resolved, but the issue persists.
Checked for VSCode extensions: I made sure that I have the necessary extensions installed for React and JavaScript development, including any MUI-related extensions, but the problem remains.
Messed with jsonconfig.js/ts.

Answer (score 0):

vsc default intellisense will not always be able to infer from node libs. One potential fix would be to add [npm intellisense extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense) to help beef up the default intellisense. There's a reason this one has 7m+ downloads.

There are also other intellisense upgrades for specific frameworks

UPDATED:

here's what vsc docs say:

- [Troubleshooting IntelliSense issues and customizing TntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.npm-intellisense&ssr=false#qna)
- [General VSC IntelliSense guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)

Comment: I use npm intellisense but still, it doesn't work. Should package intellisense for react work by default? Is reinstalling vsc a possible solution?

Comment: maybe check out the vsc links i added. It is possible to reinstall vsc easily so you're welcome to try that however it is likely something to do with how your intellisense or module is set up.